# android studio gradle build taking infinite time

Tags: android-studio

I tried to find solution on google but didn't get any useful solution. When i start new project or load any existing project on my android studio than my studio's gradle:build is not getting stop or you can say studio is stuck on gradle build.
I am attaching screen shot of both[Starting New Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5TuN.png)

[Loading Existing Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MfLg.png)

Comment: what java version are you using

Comment: Are you asking about JDK?? That is 8u66 latest one

Comment: Ok, so download and install jdk1.7 then click configure settings and change your sdk to 1.7 - sometimes are issues gradle vs. java. You can also try to update your Android Studio to 2.0Beta via Canary Chanell - with latest AS you would also get latest gradle:2.0-beta3

Comment: Back in the days of AndroidStudio 0. something, I used to start it via commandline and it used to take a lot of time because it downloaded the gradle version and my internet speed was slow.